# React App in same Server and multiple Domains

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to know if it's possible to maintain a React App on a IP (X.XXX.XXX.XX) server, and based on the URL that points to this server, render a different application.

An example of this would be to keep the application on one server, while several companies point their DNS's to the server's IP, and based on the company name, render the correct application.

I searched the internet if there is any way to do this with React Router but I didn't find

Answer (score 0):

Use nginx reverse proxy to redirect based on url which will point to your different applications.

You can maintain the same IP for all of them.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand, in this I have only one application. When I type in browser "company1.com" and "company1.com", this will redirect to same IP server, containing the same application. In the application I would need to know how to treat it.